# Add service reference failed although the service running

Tags: c#, wcf

I try to implement `WCF download upload service`, all i want to do is send from my client file to my service.
so i fount this [guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37651/WCF-Large-File-Download-Upload-Service)

This is my service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFileTransferWindowsService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void UploadDocument(string fPath, byte[] data);

    [OperationContract]
    byte[] DownloadDocument(string fPath);
}

public class FileTransferWindowsService : IFileTransferWindowsService
{
    public void UploadDocument(string fPath, byte[] data)
    {
        string filePath = fPath;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create,
                                       FileAccess.Write);
        fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        fs.Close();
    }

    public byte[] DownloadDocument(string fPath)
    {
        string filePath = fPath;
        // read the file and return the byte[
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open,
                                   FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
            return buffer;
        }
    }
}
```

app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings />
    <client />
    <services>
      <service name="WcfFileTransferServiceLibrary.FileTransferWindowsService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="ServiceHttpEndPoint" contract="WcfFileTransferServiceLibrary.IFileTransferWindowsService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="ServiceMexEndPoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://0.0.0.0:8532/FileTransferWindowsService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Start service:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    StartWCFService();
}

private void StartWCFService()
{
    try
    {
        NetTcpBinding ntcp = new NetTcpBinding();
        ntcp.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
        ntcp.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
        ntcp.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
        ntcp.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
        ntcp.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;
        ntcp.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
        ntcp.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;
        ntcp.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
        ntcp.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 10, 0);
        ntcp.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 10, 0);
        //ntcp.OpenTimeout
        //ntcp.CloseTimeout

        svh = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfFileTransferServiceLibrary.FileTransferWindowsService));
        ((ServiceBehaviorAttribute)
           svh.Description.Behaviors[0]).MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483647;
        svh.AddServiceEndpoint(
                    typeof(WcfFileTransferServiceLibrary.IFileTransferWindowsService),
                    ntcp,
                    "net.tcp://0.0.0.0:8532/FileTransferWindowsService");
        //svh = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfFileTransferServiceLibrary.IFileTransferWindowsService));
        svh.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

}
```

Also i created `Windows service project` and try to install my service (via installutil) and run this service.
after that i try to connect this service by Add service reference but it failed to connect:

**The URI prefix is not recognized.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://10.61.41.51:8532/FileTransferWindowsService/'.
Could not connect to net.tcp://10.61.41.51:8532/FileTransferWindowsService/. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:01.0011001. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 10.61.41.51:8532. 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 10.61.41.51:8532
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.**

Comment: Is the firewall allowing this port? 8532

Comment: Yes, this is not firewall issue

Comment: Check if the service is running. Maybe some exception happened and the service is not running.

Comment: The service is running

Comment: Try to connect using telnet to check if the connection can be stabilished.

Comment: i installed Telnet client and try telnet ipAddress:8532 --> Connecting To ipAddress:8532...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you did not set the security level for the connection. By default, NetTcpBinding tries to secure a connection at the transport layer, but you didn't specify that in the client.

The easiest solution is to set the security level to NONE on your server. Add this line

```
ntcp.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
```

in your StartWCFService() method.

Comment: I put it inside my OnStart() method and unfortunately that not help

Comment: Why would you put it in the OnStart() method, given that your NetTcpBinding object is not in scope there?